# Page with category list with image (ACF)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try to create list of child category with images thumbs.

I add new field to taxonomy (ACF plugin) “image_category” and now I try to add this image to the list:

```
<?php 

$args = array('parent' => 3);
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$term = get_queried_object();
$image_category = get_field('image_category', $term);

foreach($categories as $category) { 

    echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center pb-3"><img src="' . $image_category .  '"><h3><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </h3> ';
    echo '<p> <strong>Number post:</strong> '. $category->count . '</p></div>';  
}

?>
```

I see category list, name, number post. Only image dont work.

Image link dont show. I have on consol only “img src=(unknown)”. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to `print_r($image_category);`

Comment: @Bhautik Unfortunately it does not work. All image have <img src = "1">

Comment: Try this `$image_category['url'];`